# Mostrar últimos resultados porém com ordenação ASC no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, select

Gostaria de mostrar os últimos 10 resultados encontrados em uma tabela, porém com a ordenação ASC. Estou usando o seguinte:

```
$listarResultados = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE categoria = 'cateste' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10");
$listarResultados ->execute();
```

Acontece que, esse select me retorna os 10 primeiros resultados, e eu quero listar os 10 últimos porém em ordem ASC. Qual a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize uma sub-consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM teste WHERE categoria = 'cateste' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) S
ORDER BY id ASC
```